# After i reload i want to keep the local storage values

Tags: javascript, local-storage, refresh, reload, keep-alive

This is my function:

```js
function render() {
  let list = document.getElementById('myNotes');
  trashFolderModal = document.getElementById('allBlur');
  list.innerHTML = localStorage.setItem(key, text);

  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    const title = titles[i];
    const note = notes[i];
    list.innerHTML += card(title, note, i);
  }
}
```

And here is my Note Website (you can see the source code):
http://patrick-sterz.developerakademie.com/Notizblock2/index%282%29.html

Answer (score 0):

[`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) returns undefined.

I suspect you need to revisit what you want to do.

Normally we do this when the list changes

```
 localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(myListArray));
```

and when we load the page we do a

```
let listContent = localStorage.getItem("list"); 
let myListArray =  listContent ? JSON.parse(listContent) : [];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i need getItem not setItem, but please give me the exact code/function because I've been stuck on this task for 3 hours

Comment: I would need at least one hour to fix your script. It is FAR too unnecessarily complex.
Have two arrays - I have started here, but need to go. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ywnh7058/

Comment: Ok thank you so musch, i am a begiiner and cant understand your code. I do it with my own code.
But thank you, you are the best